# Creating short and long sqlplus connections with bash scripts for a X amount of time

Tags: linux, bash, oracle, shell, sqlplus

I need to create a short/long connections to oracle db using sqlplus client with a bash script for 10 minutes (for the sake of example), the difference between the two is the following:

Long connection:

- A connection established
- Every 5 - 10 seconds the connection is executing a query of some kind
- At the end of the 10 minutes, the client is terminated

Short connection:

- A connection established
- Doing a query
- Connection is closed
- repeat the procedure for 10 minutes (connections open and close, maintain a 10 connections all the time)

I have a baseline, i need to adjust it for the above mentioned scenarios (2 different bash files):

```
#!/bin/sh
for i in $(seq 1 10);
do
   echo "CREATE TABLE oracle_BEQ_$i (id NUMBER NOT NULL);
   ! sleep 30
   select * from oracle_BEQ_$i ;
   ! sleep 30
   DROP TABLE oracle_BEQ_$i;" | sqlplus <user>/<password> &
done
wait
```

This script currently only does the following:

1) Create 10 connections (simultaneously)

2) Run 3 queries

3) When finished, connections are closed

What are the adjustments i need to make for the 2 scenarios i mentioned?

Answer (score 1):

**Example 1.**
You can run script `pipe.sh` in the background. And in another session, send sql files or sql. With reconnect after run sql.

```
more pipe.sh

#!/bin/bash

rm /tmp/sqlplus_pipe.sql
mknod /tmp/sqlplus_pipe.sql p

while :
do

$ORACLE_HOME/bin/sqlplus   "system/manager" <<EOF
@/tmp/sqlplus_pipe.sql
EOF

sleep 1
done
```

run this script in backgroud

```
   nohup ./pipe.sh  >pipe_log.log 2>&1  &
```

In other bash session you can send sql file or sql  to this backgroud process.

```
oracle@esmd:/tmp> cat test2.sql >>/tmp/sqlplus_pipe.sql
oracle@esmd:/tmp> cat test2.sql >>/tmp/sqlplus_pipe.sql

oracle@esmd:/tmp> echo "select to_char(sysdate,'DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI:SS') from dual;" >>/tmp/sqlplus_pipe.sql
oracle@esmd:/tmp> echo "select to_char(sysdate,'DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI:SS') from dual;" >>/tmp/sqlplus_pipe.sql


oracle@esmd:/tmp> more test2.sql
select to_char(sysdate,'DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI:SS') from dual;



oracle@esmd:~> more pipe_log.log

SQL*Plus: Release 11.2.0.3.0 Production on Thu Aug 8 14:50:35 2019

Copyright (c) 1982, 2011, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Connected to:
Oracle Database 11g Release 11.2.0.3.0 - 64bit Production

SQL>
TO_CHAR(SYSDATE,'DD
-------------------
08-08-2019 14:50:46

SQL> Disconnected from Oracle Database 11g Release 11.2.0.3.0 - 64bit Production

SQL*Plus: Release 11.2.0.3.0 Production on Thu Aug 8 14:50:47 2019

Copyright (c) 1982, 2011, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Connected to:
Oracle Database 11g Release 11.2.0.3.0 - 64bit Production

SQL>
TO_CHAR(SYSDATE,'DD
-------------------
08-08-2019 14:50:48

SQL> Disconnected from Oracle Database 11g Release 11.2.0.3.0 - 64bit Production

SQL*Plus: Release 11.2.0.3.0 Production on Thu Aug 8 14:50:49 2019

Copyright (c) 1982, 2011, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Connected to:
Oracle Database 11g Release 11.2.0.3.0 - 64bit Production

SQL>
TO_CHAR(SYSDATE,'DD
-------------------
08-08-2019 14:50:49

SQL> Disconnected from Oracle Database 11g Release 11.2.0.3.0 - 64bit Production
```

Update.
**Example 2.**
You can run script `pipev2.sh` in the background on the Oracle database server. And in another session, send sql files or sql. Without reconnect after run sql.

```
 nohup ./pipev2.sh >output.log 2>&1 &

#!/bin/bash

rm /home/trs/db2Toora/sql/sqlplus_pipe.sql
mknod /home/trs/db2Toora/sql/sqlplus_pipe.sql p


$ORACLE_HOME/bin/sqlplus   "system/manager" <<EOF
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON 
    BEGIN
      RUN_SQL;
    END;
/
EOF


CREATE OR REPLACE DIRECTORY TEMP_DIR_CHANGE AS '/home/trs/db2Toora/sql'
/
GRANT READ ON DIRECTORY TEMP_DIR_CHANGE TO SYSTEM
/
GRANT WRITE ON DIRECTORY TEMP_DIR_CHANGE TO SYSTEM
/


    CREATE OR REPALCE PROCEDURE RUN_SQL

is
    sql_text VARCHAR2(2000);
    file_sql_name VARCHAR2(100):='sqlplus_pipe.sql';
    sql_delimiter VARCHAR2(1):=';';
    stop_script VARCHAR2(10):='%QUIT%';
    sql_output VARCHAR2(2000);
    InFile           utl_file.file_type;
    vNewLine         VARCHAR2(4000);
    k  pls_integer :=0;
    BEGIN
    dbms_output.enable;
    while k <>1
    loop
    InFile := utl_file.fopen('TEMP_DIR_CHANGE', file_sql_name,'r');

    LOOP
      BEGIN

      utl_file.get_line(InFile, vNewLine);

      if vNewLine like '%'||sql_delimiter||'%' then
         sql_text:=sql_text||vNewLine;
      dbms_output.put_line(sql_text);
       begin

        execute immediate replace(sql_text,sql_delimiter,'' ) into sql_output;

        EXCEPTION
        WHEN OTHERS THEN
        dbms_output.put_line('!---!--Error--!---!');
        dbms_output.put_line(substr(sqlerrm, 1, 500));
       end;
      dbms_output.put_line(sql_output);
      dbms_output.put_line('---------------------------------------------------------------');
      sql_text:='';
      elsif vNewLine like  stop_script then
      dbms_output.put_line('---!--QUIT--!---');
      EXIT;
      else
      sql_text:=sql_text||vNewLine;
      end if;

      EXCEPTION
        WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
        EXIT;
      END;


    END LOOP;
      if vNewLine like stop_script then
       exit;
      end if;

end loop;

    utl_file.fclose(InFile);

    END;
```

Test

```
oracle@esmd:/home/trs/db2Toora/sql> cat test2.sql >sqlplus_pipe.sql
oracle@esmd:/home/trs/db2Toora/sql> cat test2.sql >sqlplus_pipe.sql
oracle@esmd:/home/trs/db2Toora/sql> cat test2.sql >sqlplus_pipe.sql
oracle@esmd:/home/trs/db2Toora/sql> cat test2.sql >sqlplus_pipe.sql
oracle@esmd:/home/trs/db2Toora/sql> cat test2.sql >sqlplus_pipe.sql
oracle@esmd:/home/trs/db2Toora/sql> cat test2.sql >sqlplus_pipe.sql
oracle@esmd:/home/trs/db2Toora/sql> cat test2.sql >sqlplus_pipe.sql
oracle@esmd:/home/trs/db2Toora/sql> cat test2.sql >sqlplus_pipe.sql
oracle@esmd:/home/trs/db2Toora/sql> cat test2.sql >sqlplus_pipe.sql
oracle@esmd:/home/trs/db2Toora/sql> cat test2.sql >sqlplus_pipe.sql
oracle@esmd:/home/trs/db2Toora/sql> cat test2.sql >sqlplus_pipe.sql
oracle@esmd:/home/trs/db2Toora/sql> cat test2.sql >sqlplus_pipe.sql
oracle@esmd:/home/trs/db2Toora/sql> echo 'QUIT'  >sqlplus_pipe.sql
oracle@esmd:/home/trs/db2Toora/sql>


oracle@esmd:/home/trs/db2Toora/sql> more test2.sql
select to_char(sysdate,'DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI:SS')
from dual
;
select to_char(sysdate,'DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI')
from dual
;


nohup: ignoring input

SQL*Plus: Release 11.2.0.3.0 Production on Tue Aug 13 10:11:23 2019

Copyright (c) 1982, 2011, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Connected to:
Oracle Database 11g Release 11.2.0.3.0 - 64bit Production

SQL> SQL>   2    3    4  select to_char(sysdate,'DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI:SS')  from dual;
13-08-2019 10:11:34
---------------------------------------------------------------
select to_char(sysdate,'DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI')  from dual;
13-08-2019 10:11
---------------------------------------------------------------
select to_char(sysdate,'DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI:SS')  from dual;
13-08-2019 10:11:35
---------------------------------------------------------------
select to_char(sysdate,'DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI')  from dual;
13-08-2019 10:11
---------------------------------------------------------------
select to_char(sysdate,'DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI:SS')  from dual;
13-08-2019 10:11:35
---------------------------------------------------------------
select to_char(sysdate,'DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI')  from dual;
13-08-2019 10:11
---------------------------------------------------------------
select to_char(sysdate,'DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI:SS')  from dual;
13-08-2019 10:11:36
---------------------------------------------------------------
select to_char(sysdate,'DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI')  from dual;
13-08-2019 10:11
---------------------------------------------------------------
select to_char(sysdate,'DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI:SS')  from dual;
13-08-2019 10:11:36
---------------------------------------------------------------
select to_char(sysdate,'DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI')  from dual;
13-08-2019 10:11
---------------------------------------------------------------
select to_char(sysdate,'DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI:SS')  from dual;
13-08-2019 10:11:37
---------------------------------------------------------------
select to_char(sysdate,'DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI')  from dual;
13-08-2019 12:19
---------------------------------------------------------------
---!--QUIT--!---

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL> Disconnected from Oracle Database 11g Release 11.2.0.3.0 - 64bit Production
```

Comment: You did a really marvelous job explaining, but do you mind refactor the code so it will be more friendly and understandable like -> create a script called X, it contains the following : ..., you run it like this.... especially in example 2 which is overwhelming for me, thank you very much